# Handling HTTP requests forwarded from Firebase Hosting to Cloud Functions

Tags: typescript, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I'm currently trying to patch data to my Firestore database using http. I'm trying to do this without using a external server, so by using Firebase Hosting and Functions.

First I initialized my Firebase project and I imported express, body-parser and firebase-functions-helper into the functions.

Then I added this to my firebase.json, so the source is linked to the exact function

```
 "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/api/v1/**",
        "function": "webApi"
      }
    ]
```

Second, I wrote this typescript that should upload the data from the HTTP patch to the Firestore database. This is stored in functions/src/index.ts

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as firebaseHelper from 'firebase-functions-helper/dist';
import * as express from 'express';
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const db = admin.firestore();

const app = express();
const main = express();

main.use(bodyParser.json());
main.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
main.use('/api/v1/', app);

const sensorsCollection = 'sensors';
export const webApi = functions.https.onRequest(main);

app.patch('/sensor/:sensorId', async(req, res) => {
    try{
        await firebaseHelper.firestore.updateDocument(db, sensorsCollection, req.params.sensorId, req.body);
        res.status(200).send('Update Success');
    }catch(error){
        res.status(204).send('Patch Error');
    }
})
```

But when I use postman to patch data to https://my-project.com/api/v1/document-id
it gives a 404-error containing: "Cannot PATCH /api/v1/XXX"

I double checked I have the exact document Id and I check if I have proper JSON data. Does somebody know the awnser and please help me?

Comment: Please edit the question to show exactly how you are invoking this function.

Comment: @DougStevenson I changed it, sorry my bad.

Comment: I still don't see how you are invoking this function.  What are you doing that should make this function run?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience I hope it is better know. I haven't used stackoverflow in a long time.

Comment: Your question should explain how exactly how you are using postman to make the request.  What is the URL you're using?  What would we do if we wanted to duplicate this issue on our own?

Comment: The URL i'm using is the https://project-name.firebaseapp.com/api/v1/document-id

Comment: It sounds like you're also using Firebase Hosting to proxy the requests to the function.  Please edit the question to explain how you're doing that.  Show the configuration file where you forward the request to the function.

Comment: @DougStevenson Changed it

Comment: OK, you should now give the actual URL you're using, not "XXXX".  Does it match the route defined in your code?  If everything does not match exactly, you will get that error.

Comment: https://camper-a2d7b.firebaseapp.com/api/v1/OaSmA27EGQV3urL6fO9g and this is my database structure https://prnt.sc/rm52ve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL just does not match your route.  Your route is set to trigger on paths that match /sensor/*:

```
app.patch('/sensor/:sensorId', async(req, res) => {
```

But your URL doesn't even have "sensor" anywhere in its path:

```
/api/v1/OaSmA27EGQV3urL6fO9g
```

You should adjust your path to match what's handled by your route. Perhaps you meant something more like this:

```
/api/v1/sensor/OaSmA27EGQV3urL6fO9g
```

Comment: It works thanks! do you maybe know how I can put data into an array structured like this? https://prnt.sc/rm605r

Comment: If you have another question, post it separately.